Zabbix Proxmox VE by HTTP template documentation is not useful
https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/proxmox
This document desperately needs to be updated. I was able to create an API user and apply settings similar to what is specified in the doc but I'm not confident they will work.
Parts of it make no sense at all. For example, it says we need to apply permissions to the token we created. There is simply no way to do this in the PVE web interface.
Is anyone using this template? If so, can you point me in the right direction regarding the token permissions? I do prefer using the shell.

I’m voting to close this question because it's the repeat of this one by the same user: https://serverfault.com/questions/1161542/how-do-i-set-necessary-access-levels-on-an-proxmox-api-token , and the other question is much more clear already and it's answerable right away.

It actually is possible to what the documentation suggests in the Proxmox web interface. Feel free to close and delete this question.

Please, delete it yourself. It's not useful, honestly.
