How do I set "necessary access levels" on an proxmox API token?
I'm setting up a Zabbix template for proxmox (Proxmox VE by HTTP) and ran into something that didn't make sense.
Please provide the necessary access levels for both the User and the Token:

Check: ["perm","/",["Sys.Audit"]]
Check: ["perm","/storage",["Datastore.Audit"]]
Check: ["perm","/vms",["VM.Audit"]]

The GUI (http interface) does not provide such functionality. Perhaps there's a way to do this using a shell command. Does anyone know how to do this?
Thanks.

I frequently find GUIs confusing, quirky and too subtle. I found the Proxmox GUI frustrating.

GUI does provide that functionality. You create a new role that has these permissions, and assign that role to your user and token. Or use premade PVEAuditor which exists exactly for such purposes. It has slightly wider permissions, but these extra permissions are readonly and, generally speaking, they are all reasonable to have for the monitoring system; it's the deficiency of the template that it doesn't know how to use them.
If you want to do that using CLI, the route will be the same: create a role and assign it.

I needed to understand that I had to select the menu item Permissions in the Datacenter view and then use the Add Group Permissions or API Token Permission drop-down menu item.
Permissions does not look like a "functional" menu item to me. It seemed like an inert menu title rather than something I could actually invoke by selecting then doing something else while it was selected. Sorry, but it's too subtle. I cannot possibly be the only person who has been baffled by this odd design choice.

